# Calculating the absorption cross-section for Helium in a strong oscillating external IR field -> AC Stark Shift (Autler-Townes Splitting)

Tags: schroedinger-equation, non-linear-systems, non-linear-optics

I try to obtain the absorption cross-section for atomic helium, in a strong and oscillating IR field, for when a second - XUV - pulse is probing the system. I think the only way of doing this is to calculate the time-dependent Schrödinger equation (tdse) and get the dipole response of the system.

I am asking if anyone knows hands-on examples for how to calculate the tdse for such a system and how to get the dipole moment out of these calculations.

I am aware that there won't be a complete example waiting for me, but anything related (e.g. Hydrogen in oscillating IR field) would be a great help.

I am an experimental physicist, with a minor theoretical background. I know, e.g., QPROP for solving the tdse. But I'm not having a lot of experience with that. I mostly code Python and I guess solving the tdse in Python could be possible in QuTiP ?!

For solving the DC Stark shift, even for Helium, there are a lot of solutions available:

- https://github.com/aa-morgan/helium-stark-zeeman
- The CMISTARK Package

but these are not applicable to the AC problem.

Comment: If you want to have a look at a very pedagogical and instructive introduction into how one can solve the TDSE for an atom exposed to an intense laser field you should have a look at ''Anatomy of Strong Field Ionization'' by Ivanov, Spanner and Smirnova (2005).